# Query data stored in MongoDB by date & time

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to count the number of objects which were stored in the MongoDB after a certain time. Date is stored in MongoDB in following format.

```
 "clickTime" : ISODate("2016-07-09T07:17:29.932Z")
```

I wrote the following code to count the objects but it is giving me `_count = 0`, while it should give me `_count = 1`. I am doing this in Django

```
def Count(request):
    time_from = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)

    ## today's count
    d1 = datetime.date.today()
    start1 = datetime.datetime.combine(d1,time_from)
    end1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    count1 = utils.Processor1(collect,start1,end1)
```

this is my utils file

```
 def Processor1(collect,start,end):
   _count = collect.find({"clickTime":{"$gte":start,"$lte":end}}).count()
   return _count
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure of what type your `start` and `end` vars are according to your question but try it when setting them to `datetime` instances like below:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 9, 12, 21, 25, 366)
```

Comment: I have edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: I just setup a test database with some sample documents with a date & time like yours and queried it with success. Could you try collect.find({}).count() in your Processor1 function and check whether it returns something > 0 just to check that you targeting the right collection?